# Python-docx How to add underline to inserted image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

With python-docx when inserting an image of a signature, how do I underline the image like a signature line? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
p = Document().add_paragraph.add_run()
p.add_picture('ImageName.jpg', width=Inches(1.83))
p.font.underline = True
```

The key is to apply the underline to the prior run, not the image.